# Is there something like transfer acceleration in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I would like to create an Azure Storage Account, and use blob storage in the region US West.

However my business needs is to upload/download files from all over the world and not just US West.
When I download/upload files from India or places that are far from US West, there is a severe degradation in performance.

For downloads I could use [Geo Redundant read replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy). This partially solves the problem. However the this is increasing the cost significantly. Also the time take for replication is several minutes and this is not fitting for me.

In AWS S3 storage, there is a feature called [transfer acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/transfer-acceleration/#:%7E:text=S3%20Transfer%20Acceleration%20(S3TA)%20reduces,to%20S3%20for%20remote%20applications.). Transfer acceleration speeds up the uploads/downloads by optimizing the routing of packets. Is there any similar feature in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json)(AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy blobs or files to or from a storage account. This article helps you download AzCopy, connect to your storage account, and then transfer files.) [Fast Data Transfer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/fast-data-transfer/) or [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/)(A fully managed, serverless data integration solution for ingesting, preparing, and transforming all your data at scale.)

[High-Throughput with Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/high-throughput-with-azure-blob-storage/)

You should look at the Azure Storage library https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/

You should also take into account the performance guidelines from the Azure Storage Team https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/

This article provides an overview of some of the common Azure data transfer solutions. The article also links out to recommended options depending on the network bandwidth in your environment and the size of the data you intend to transfer. [Choose an Azure solution for data transfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-choose-data-transfer-solution)